# a program to monitor a directory on Linux

Tags: c++, c, perl, unix

There is a directory where a buddy adds new builds of a product.

The listing looks like this

```
$ ls path-to-dir/
01
02
03
04
$
```

where the numbers listed are not files but names of directories containing the builds.

I have to manually go and check every time whether there is a new build or not. **I am looking for a way to automate this, so that the program can send an email to some people (including me) whenever `path-to-dir/` is updated.**

- Do we have an already existing utility or a Perl library that does this?

  [inotify.h](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) does something similar, but it is not supported on my kernel (2.6.9).

I think there can be an easy way in Perl.

- Do you think this will work?

  > Keep running a loop in Perl that does a `ls path-to-dir/` after, say, every 5 minutes and stores the results in an array. If it finds that the new results are different from the old results, it sends out an email using [Mail](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=19430) or [Email](http://www.perlfect.com/articles/sendmail.shtml).

Comment: Why can you not upgrade the kernel - that's pretty old now, the latest  stable kernels now is 2.6.34.5 and 2.6.35.4 respectively....

Comment: @tommieb75: company machine => not possible.

Comment: Knowing when the build is done will be the toughy. Perhaps `mail -s "build done" Lazer` as the last step in `make build`?

Comment: maybe cron job with simething like make?

Comment: @Lazer: ahhh ok... company policy so... the easiest is to run a loop and sleep every 5 mins then mail it... you answered yourself! :) Good luck with it. :)

Comment: I always want to ask in such a case if IT department is there to support you or if you are there to justify IT existence... If you can't update a kernel, file a ticket to your IT and ask them to provide solution. You may just find out that they CAN upgrade a kernel.. (yeah, I am dreaming).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking for different `ls` output would send a message even when something is deleted or renamed in the directory. You could instead look for files with an mtime newer than the last message sent.

Here's an example in bash, you can run it every 5 minutes:

```
now=`date +%Y%m%d%H%M.%S`

if [ ! -f "/path/to/cache/file" ] || [ -n "`find /path/to/build/dir -type f -newer /path/to/cache/file`" ]
then
    touch /path/to/cache/file -t "$now"
    sendmail -t <<< "
To: aaa@bbb.ccc
To: xxx@yyy.zzz
Subject: New files found

Dear friend,
I have found a couple of new files.
"
fi
```

Comment: [How would it look like in C shell script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692137/whats-wrong-with-this-c-shell-script)?

Answer (score 5):

If you're going for perl, I'm sure the excellent [`File::ChangeNotify`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::ChangeNotify) module will be extremely helpful to you. It can use `inotify`, if available, but also all sorts of other file-watching mechanisms provided by different platforms. Also, as a fallback, it has its own watching implementation, which works on every platform, but is less efficient than the specialized ones.

Answer (score 1):

Can't it be a simple shell script?

```
while :;do
        n = 'ls -al path-to-dir | wc -l'
        if n -gt old_n
    # your Mail code here; set old_n=n also
        fi
   sleep 5
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a loop in Perl as described would do the trick.

You could keep a track of when the directory was last modified; if it hasn't changed, there isn't a new build.  If it has changed, an old build might have been deleted or a new one added.  You probably don't want to send alerts when old builds are removed; it is crucial that the email is sent when new builds are added.

However, I think that [msw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/282912/msw) has the right idea; the build should notify when it has completed the copy out to the new directory.  It should be a script that can be changed to notify the correct list of people - rather than a hard-wired list of names in the makefile or whatever other build control system you use.

Answer (score 0):

you could use [dnotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dnotify)  it is the predecessor of inotify and should be available on your kernel. It is still supported by newer kernels.